# Why is pull.rebase a "possibly dangerous operation"?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-pull, git-config

The [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) states that `pull.rebase` is a "possibly dangerous operation", but why is this?  If you get merge conflicts, you can abandon the merge... but if you get conflicts while rebasing, you can equally abandon the rebase.  You're no more likely to lose data when you have this setting on, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "possibly dangerous" doesn't mean that it is dangerous for losing your work, but because you are **rewriting history**.

The danger lies in the fact that the `sha` of each commit you rebase will change, and if any other developer keeps references to that `sha`, his reference will be broken.